# how does std::pmr::memory_resource makes performance difference with std::container?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, c++17

for exmaple `std::pmr::vector<int>l1` is faster than regular `vector<int> l2`. how?

what makes a major difference? How is it different than a smart pointer?

Comment: They're completely orthogonal concepts. PMR is an allocator-system, not an RAII system. This is a fairly big subject; you may want to [watch](https://youtu.be/q6A7cKFXjY0) [these](https://youtu.be/RLezJuqNcEQ) [videos](https://youtu.be/ebn1C-mTFVk). They give  a nice overview of PMR and related technologies.

Comment: Thank you @ravnsgaard, but my main concern is with performance, pmr is not some kinda different memory right?it's a technique for memory managment right?

Comment: It's more akin to a memory pool. You can make your container allocate objects in memory _you_ decide where is. If you know you mostly only need a certain amount of objects allocated, you can use the local stack for your memory and avoid dynamic allocation altogether. I recommend watching the first video above. It is less than ten minutes and talks only about typical usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`template <typename T> std::pmr::vector<T>` is an alias for `template <typename T> std::vector<T, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<T>>`. The *only* runtime differences are in how it allocates and deallocates memory for the elements.

The advantage of `std::pmr::vector` is that different allocation strategies don't have different types, so you can have *one* function `void frobnicate(const std::pmr::vector<int> &);`, instead of *multiple* `template <typename A> void frobnicate(const std::vector<int, A> &);`, if different parts of your program have different allocation requirements.

The disadvantage is there is (usually) some overhead with the type-erasure.

If you only use one allocator (e.g. the default, `std::allocator`), there's no point using `std::pmr`